# Making tableView cell bigger when clicked

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How would I make my cell bigger when I click on it ?

This is my current code that isn't working.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [feedsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    ell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 320.0, 250.0);
    NSLog(@"[CELL CLICK] %i", indexPath.row);

    [feedsTableView beginUpdates];
    [feedsTableView endUpdates];

    [feedsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath == selectedIndex)
    return 80.0f;
  else
    return 50.0f;
}
```

Then in the didSelectRowAtIndex set the selectedIndex variable and reload the tableview like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  selectedIndex = indexPath;
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}
```